# How can I voiceover in blender video editing?

Tags: edit-mode

I am beginner in blender. But I am using blender. Because blender is free for all. I am a premire pro user but I love blender for their good functional option in blender. I can not voiceover in  blender video editing. Do you have any solution? I want voiceover option in blender. Also need voice editing option in new version. Please make voiceover option in blender.

Comment: it looks more like a request than a question, maybe ask here: https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/

Comment: If this is because Blender is for free, use Audacity, is also for free and for audio editing